# failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I am facing an issue during the HA self-managed Kubernetes cluster setup.

```
Version is v1.22.0.

ubuntu 20.04
```

I am facing issues like as below,

```
 "Failed to load kubelet config file" err="failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file \"/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml\", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory" path="/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
```

I am facing an issue on the master node during setup,

Have any one idea to resolve this.

Comment: `Have any one idea to resolve this.` Yes, make sure the file is present under the given path.

Comment: have checked its present in same path but still status of kubelet is failed

Comment: And its permissions are sufficient?

Comment: Give output of ls -altrh /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml

Comment: Is this issue resolved ?

Comment: @imaheshwarans, what is your Kubernetes version? What is the exact error you are getting? It seems the OP has abandoned the question; feel free to add your error text